# Shrunk Chrome extension popup

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I created a [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/user_interface/#popup) for a Chrome extension. This is the popup source code:

```html
<form>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email">
  <input type="submit">
  <p>Hello, world! This is a paragraph. And this is some text.</p>
</form>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

And this is how it should look:
[image]

As you see, the elements aren't in the right position.

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can it be prevented?

Comment: This is an ancient bug in all extension pages which is still not fixed: the default font-size is 75%. The workaround is to add your own e.g. `body{font-size:15px}`

Comment: @wOxxOm: That's not the main problem: just look at the elements and their position.

Comment: Sizing is indeed a separate problem. The popup is auto-sized to content, so its inherent width is 0, which causes your content to overflow and wrap. You can add min-width to your body.

Comment: Change `<body>` to `<body style="min-width:350px">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why

According to the source of Chromium on 1/3/23, the default minimum width and height is 25px by 25px:

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/views/extensions/extension_popup.h;l=60

```
// The min/max height of popups.
// The minimum is just a little larger than the size of the button itself.
// The maximum is an arbitrary number and should be smaller than most screens.
static constexpr gfx::Size kMinSize = {25, 25};
static constexpr gfx::Size kMaxSize = {800, 600};
```

Your content appears to be out of position, because it's trying to fit within that width of 25px, but overflows instead.

## Prevention

Therefore, at least one of the parent elements of your content needs to be styled with a width that will fit your content.

### Determine the Parent Element to Style

In your case, the parent / container element `<form>` could be styled.

### Choose a Style Approach

There is more than one way to force the parent element's width to be a certain length, percentage, or keyword value:

- In-line CSS within HTML `<form>` tag

  - `<form style="min-width: max-content !important">...</form>`
- Internal CSS:

  - `<style> form { min-width: max-content !important; } </style>`
- External CSS:

  - `form { min-width: max-content !important; }`

### Mobile

For mobile web development, I would recommend to not use `height` as another user suggested. Even though it's within a popup, please use `min-height` instead. Otherwise you might have overlapping container elements, like I did until I used min-height.

Comment: Is it OK to use `width: max-content;` instead? I just tried it and it seems to be working.

Comment: This is a chrome extension, it's not possible for it to be on mobile.

Comment: @MrDiamond Yes it is possible on mobile chromium browsers that support Chrome extensions, like Kiwi. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: @Mori Yes, it's OK for now in this snippet/example. Feel free to use `width: max-content;` until you come across a use-case where your formatting doesn't look right on mobile, small screens, resized windows snapped to a quarter or 1/16 of the monitor, etc. I've only had trouble with `height` and use `min-height` instead, but I mainly scroll in y not x. I haven't tested whether `min-width` is required for sites or popups that may need to scroll in x.

Comment: I only brought up mobile among other things, because this question states "Mori is looking for a canonical answer," which I interpreted as a blanket answer for different use cases not just Mori's specific snippet. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185778/meaning-of-canonical-answer-required-bounty-category

Answer (score 1):

This is because the body of the popup is not wide enough to fit this. To change this, you can add super simple CSS to extend the width of the popup.

```css
body {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

You can change this to whatever you would like, just as long as it fits the form.

This happens because the default width of the extension popup is very small, and prefers to stay small. It is encouraged that you change it, to fit your content.

[image]